# how to generate random numbers with lognormal distribution and with specified geometric mean and geometric standard deviationin Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would  like to generate some random numbers log-normally distributed with a specified geometric mean (GM) and geometric standard deviation (GSD), say GM=10 and GSD=2.5. 
How do I do that in Matlab? I looked up Matlab's help and found this link but I want to use my initial inputs as GM and GSD rather than mean and variance.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/lognrnd.html

Comment: You may get a better audience at the math version of this site [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or the stats version [here](stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) says that the geometric mean of the log-normal distribution is `exp(µ)` and the geometric standard deviation is `exp(sigma)`. So just do:

```
rn = lognrnd(log(GM), log(GSD));
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to write as stackoverflow doesn't have maths markup (might be some LaTeX mistakes below), but if we define $m_a$ and $m_g$ as the arithmetic and geometric means, and $s_a$ and $s_g$ as the arithmetic and geometric standard deviations:

$m_a = exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2),$

$m_g = m_a exp(-\sigma^2/2),$

and

$s_g = exp(\sigma) <-> \sigma = log(s_g)$

If $m_g = 10$, $m_a = 10/\exp(-\sigma^2/2) = 10/\exp(-\log(s_g)^2/2)$, and

$s_g = (\exp(\sigma^2)-1)\exp(\mu
\s_g = \exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2)\sqrt{\exp(\sigma^2 - 1)} . $

So:

```
 GM = 10; GSD = 2.5;
 M = 10/exp(-log(GSD)^2/2);
 V = exp(log(GM)+log(GSD)^2/2)*sqrt(exp(log(GSD)^2)-1);
 MU = log(M^2 / sqrt(V+M^2))
 SIGMA = sqrt(log(V/M^2 + 1))

 >> lognrnd(MU, SIGMA, 10, 1)

 ans =

   18.5128
   15.9902
   10.3143
   13.0549
   16.0934
   38.5006
   30.9571
   10.1976
   33.2538
   17.8427
```

Comment: Note that the parameters `mu` and `sigma` in `lognrandn` are the arithmetic mean and standard deviation of the associated **normal** distribution (not the generated log-normal distribution). In particular, the distribution generated with the suggested approach will not have 10 as geometric mean (observe that from the 10 samples, none is smaller than 10).

Comment: Thank you tdc for your answer.  I checked numbers generated by your approach and the GM is indeed greater than 10.

Comment: Ah sorry - decidedly unhelpful paramterisation from matlab I'd say!